# Flash Error #1063 Argument count mismatch

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, away3d, flartoolkit, argument-error

I'm getting the following strange error:

*ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on Away3DLiteSprite(). Expected 4, got 0.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're calling `Away3DLiteSprite()` without providing any parameters. Locate where in your code that function is being called and make sure you pass in the `flarManager`, `viewportWidth`, `viewportHeight` and `stage` parameters.